# HTML Chat : Is appending text the best/only way?

Tags: html

All the in-browser chat rooms I have seen so far append messages into the html.

Questions: Is this the proper way to do browser based chat rooms? Will I run into any problems if I implement a browser based chat like this?

Comment: How can you do it differently? You're not suggesting the users should refresh the page each time to see messages?

Comment: Surely you've answered your own question if "All the in-browser chat rooms" do this.

Comment: @m.edmondson 'everyone' is doing it does mean it is the right solution.

Comment: "All the in-browser chat rooms"..."I have seen so far". I was wondering if they did it this way because they're meant to be tutorials or teaching examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is how to do chat rooms in html. There is no practical way to display more text without changing the html in some way.

The only problem you might want to watch out for is auto scrolling. The browser will not continue to scroll down to display the next new message (assuming you're appending at the bottom) unless you code auto scrolling into the javascript, so you should probably do that.

Comment: `scrollTop` javascript property ftw https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

It should work cross browser, but you might have problems with IE and `document.getElementById();`

Comment: Did you have any specific problems in mind? `getElementById` works fine in all versions of IE.

Comment: Yes, it does but depending on the version it can result in unexpected results. I cannot list all of the problems here, but I have run into problems in the past. See this blog post I found while searching for more information: http://www.impressivewebs.com/avoiding-problems-with-javascript-getelementbyid-method-in-internet-explorer-7/

Comment: okay, so you're talking about the `name` --> `id` bug. That's a much bigger bug than just `getElementById`. But it's trivial to work around and well known. In any case, the question didn't ask about how to implement it; he could just as easily use jQuery to do it, in which case your point is moot.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know very much about JQuery as I usually use pure Javascript.